# How to use invokationCommandAction with MVVM Light v5?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a project which target is .NET 4.5.1. I install the MVVM Light nuget, and the manager install the version 5 of MVVM Light.

In this version I can't use EventToCommand, I have to use incovationCommandAction, so I need to add th my axml this code in the header:

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

and this code to add a command to my control:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerPressed">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                    Command="{Binding ShowPositionCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                    InputConverter="{StaticResource MouseButtonEventArgsToPointConverter}"
                    InputConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

However, I get an error that say core:EventTriggerBehavior is not available in Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.

Which is the problem? the example I get it [from this link](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/)

Is it possible to use MVVM Light v4.3 in a project which target is 4.5.1?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For event triggers i'm using the following code - let me know if this helps you out.
(this is using MVVM Light version 5, targeting .NET 4.5)

```
xmlns:j="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"


<j:Interaction.Triggers>
        <j:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"> 
            </cmd:EventToCommand>
        </j:EventTrigger>
</j:Interaction.Triggers>
```